# Spring Social ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection is returning "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-social

I'm creating a controller to register an user that has logged in using oauth2 but whenever I try to get the connection using ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request) it says the function does not exist.

This is my controller:

```
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInUtils;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {

                    Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);

                    RegistrationForm registration = createRegistrationDTO(connection);
                    model.addAttribute("user", registration);

                    return "user/registrationForm";
    }
```

Those are the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection` was removed in Spring Social 1.1.2, however the documentation wasn't updated to reflect this. The example code at [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/signup/SignupController.java) shows this instead

```
@Inject
public SignupController(AccountRepository accountRepository, 
                        ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
                        UsersConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    this.providerSignInUtils = new ProviderSignInUtils(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public SignupForm signupForm(WebRequest request) {
    Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
    if (connection != null) {
        request.setAttribute("message", new Message(MessageType.INFO, "Your " + StringUtils.capitalize(connection.getKey().getProviderId()) + " account is not associated with a Spring Social Showcase account. If you're new, please sign up."), WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        return SignupForm.fromProviderUser(connection.fetchUserProfile());
    } else {
        return new SignupForm();
    }
}
```

You need to create your own local `providerSignInUtils` so it has access to the `connectionFactoryLocator` and `connectionRepository`.

Comment: Thanks you very much!